# SharePoint User Profiles Deleted

Tags: my-site, user-profile-service

I had an strange issue 3 weeks before and i was wondering if you guys can help me with that .

We have setup my sites in our environment  and we have about 5000 profiles and everyday at 1.00 am an incremental synchronization is scheduled and its been running nice for about 1 year without any issues .last week an incremental sync ran and it had deleted all the profiles leaving about 300 in our UPS application (Again i don't know why these were left !!!)

When i debugged further using the Forefront Client and SQL there were about 4000 accounts were marked for deletion and the my site cleanup job has done its job and deleted all of them .So the next day as part of contingency i restored the profile DB from previous day backup and all the 5000 profiles were there so i ran a full sync and to my surprise all the profiles were again deleted

So this time i had asked our DBA to restore the backup again and disabled the my site cleanup job and deleted and recreated all the sync connections and ran a full sync and to my surprise all the profiles were there and they are back to normal .After than i ran 3 more times full sync and incremental sync just to verify and everything is working normal and after that i scheduled back our incremental sync and its running fine for the past week

So now i am wondering what actually caused the issue because i don't want this to happen again .

More Info

- None of the accounts that are deleted are disabled  in AD
- None of the    filters in the connections were changed in the past 6 months
- But sometimes our User profile sync is stopping automatically and i am just starting
  the service back again

Comment: it's too bad you removed the connections before you resolved why the connections filter began failing. I suspect that something changed in AD. FOr example someone renamed the cuser container OU or something that caused the filter to no longer match the employees. What's the difference between those that were deleted and those that remained? The log entrieds in MIISClient should tell you what happened.

Comment: Yes as it was a live prod environment i had to bring back the profiles ASAP .so i didn't have much time to debug .The ones that were remained are the users who had accessed the SharePoint sites on that day .MISSClient i just saw that the profiles marked for deletion .CAn you explain about the logs in that and how to verify

Comment: SharePoint recreated the User Profiles as folks accessed the environment. The logs are accessed through the MIISClient UI. When you deprovisioned the UPA it deletes the data IIRC.